# in loop / assignment: expected type parameter `T`, found `&T`

Tags: rust

[error on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2f1a2f22c86f66f0a64d18368f651379)

```
enum Error {}

fn foo<T>(bars: Vec<T>) -> Result<Vec<T>, Error>
{
    let mut baz = vec![];
    for bar in bars.iter(){
            baz.push(bar);
    }
    Ok(baz)
}
```

nothing like & or * seems to lead to a solution, also because `bar` is an external crate

```
enum Error {}

fn foo<T>(bars: Vec<T>) -> Result<Vec<T>, Error>
{
    let mut baz = vec![];
    for &bar in bars.iter(){
            baz.push(bar);
    }
    Ok(*baz)
}
```

what is causing the issue? How would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[solution in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50ab530280b56f0b01fac0cedabf2b5f)

the problem was, that `.iter()` always returns referenced values.
[the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/) reveals the following:

```
There are three common methods which can create iterators from a collection:

    iter(), which iterates over &T.
    iter_mut(), which iterates over &mut T.
    into_iter(), which iterates over T.
```

```
enum Error {}

fn foo<T>(bars: Vec<T>) -> Result<Vec<T>, Error>
{
    let mut baz = vec![];
    for bar in bars.into_iter(){
            baz.push(bar);
    }
    Ok(baz)
}
```

Comment: Or just `for bar in bars` – `into_iter()` is called implicitly by the for loop.